# How can I query datetime in SQLite database

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime

Here is my code:

```
string sql = string.Format("select * from StockInTb  ");

DataTable dt = dataAccess.GetDataTable(sql);
UploadService.UploadClient client = new UploadService.UploadClient();

if (client.UpdateTest(dt))
{
    MessageBox.Show("suceess");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("fail");
}
```

Here is my `dataaccess` class:

```
        private static string connString;
        private static SQLiteConnection conn;

        public SQLiteDataAccess()
        {
            connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
        }

        private void OpenConn()
        {
            try
            {
                if (conn == null)
                {
                    conn = new SQLiteConnection(connString);
                }

                if (conn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    conn.Open();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogUtil.Log("ex:" + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void CloseConn()
        {
            try
            {
                if (conn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogUtil.Log("ex:" + ex.Message);
            }
        }

public System.Data.DataTable GetDataTable(string sql)
        {
            DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                OpenConn();
                SQLiteDataAdapter adpter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, conn);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adpter.Fill(ds);//here,I got the error.
                if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    dtResult = ds.Tables[0];
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogUtil.Log("ex:" + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseConn();
            }

            return dtResult;
        }
```

I got the error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

The database is SQLite, and table `StockInTb` contains some columns which type is `datetime`.
I've found some solutions like `datetime.toString(s)`, but that's not what I need.

I don't know how to solve this odd problem. If somebody knows the answers, please tell me.

Thanks.

Comment: Please update question with the code where you get the `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime` error

Comment: I've edited,please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use parameter as below, Assume You have Column called `MyDateTime` and type is DateTime in your  StockInTb  Table then your query should be change as below. 
Note that  `@InputDate` going to add bay using  `Command.Parameters.Add` method. Need to give the same name in both places and you can directly set parameter from DateTime object ( here it is named as `InputDate`

```
Command.CommandText = "select * from StockInTb where MyDateTime = @InputDate";

Command.Parameters.Add("@InputDate", InputDate);
```

Comment: thank you frist,but I just want query like this "select * from StockInTb" without the where condition.

Comment: @KevinKong So whare you want to query with date time field?

Comment: I want to query all of the data in the table "StockInTb",and the "StockInTb" contains the datetime type columns. And I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I've found the where the problem was.In the table,the time format was '2012-1-1 0:00:00' so the ADO.NET can't convert it. The problems was located in the Sqlite.dll. I found another version edited by other guys which works. 
here is the download link:http://files.cnblogs.com/chinull/sqlite.rar